# Geting the crash respond, Abort trap: 6, when I try the pyvisa

Tags: python-3.x, pyvisa

I try to run in the python shell some commands by using pyvisa. So I do the  following as they show [here](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/master/), but when I execute `rm = visa.ResourceManager()` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it crashes, and I get the `Abort trap: 6 respond`. Does anyone know what is wrong? My Python version is 3.6.3, and I am using the macOS Mojave.

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
```

Comment: Thanks pushkin for editing of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem last week and was finally able to fix this issue on my mac.
Went on the NI forum and found the solution. They suggested rebooting your machine, go on System Preferences > Security and Privacy and allowing NI software to run on your machine. Link to a more details below, hope this helps.

https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/Abort-problem-after-installing-NI-VISA-18-0-0-and-PyVisa-on-Mac/m-p/3819283/highlight/true#M77872

Comment: Please include the key info from the link directly in your answer.